# Two UIScrollView's on top of each other?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I'm working on a iphone game, and part of it includes a section where you scroll horizontally through a list of images (which have transparent backgrounds).

but I also want to be able to vertically scroll and change the background image, without the image in the horizontal scroll view changing.

I have the horizontal scrollview working now, and I've placed a second scrollview behind it for the vertical scrollview, but obviously the vertical scrollview doesn't catch the up/down swipes.

Is there some way to push vertical swipes through to the second scrollview, but catch the horizontal swipes on the first?

Mike

Comment: You can do it like that. Why don't you use single scroll view and make it scroll in both directions?

Comment: Well, I want the "background" scroll view to scroll behind the "forground" scroll view independently- so swiping left/right changes the front image, but the back image stays- while swiping up/down changes the back image, but the front one stays.

Answer (score 0):

IF you implement the scrollViewDidScroll Delegate for the first scroll view and catch the scroll offset, you can pass the same to the second scroll and control how the offset moves on the second scroll.

Comment: I tried implementing it like that- but- and I'm not sure about this- because the foreground image is exactly the same height as the iphone (since it's only scrolls left/right), iOS disables vertical scrolling- because I wasn't catching any changes on the y-axis from the scrolLViewDidScroll event.

Comment: I know it's possible- I found an app called "monster mixer" that does exactly what I want- just not sure how they did it.

Comment: check with the UIResponder chain. You can push events you don't want to handle and pass them up the responder chain. I don't know if it specifically solves your problem.